# Checkbox con valor "on" al hacer POST

Tags: php, html, post

Tengo un form con el que paso una serie de datos a otra página y entre ellos una serie de checkboxes los cuales me dan valor "on" cuando consulto el array.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" id='login' method="post" action="corregido.php">
......
<input type="checkbox" id="<?php echo $idpregunta;?>" name="impugnar[]" value"<?php echo $k;?>"> Impugar pregunta...
......
</form>
```

Y en cuanto a corregido.php

```
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION["id_user"])) {
    header("index.php");
}
require 'dbcon.php';
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');

if(!empty($_POST['impugnar'])) {    
        foreach($_POST['impugnar'] as $value){
            echo "value : ".$value.'<br/>';
        }
}
```

Tengo el resto de código bien porque me pasa otra serie de inputs pero el checkbox se limita a pasar todos los que están checked como "on" y el resto no los pasa. Me gustaría que pasaran todos con el valor de cada checkbox.

Comment: Hola Vieira, te falto poner un `=`, es decir, `value="<?php echo $k;?>`. Es solo por eso.

Comment: Gracias Marcos . La verdad que los despistes a veces...

Answer (score 0):

Podrías hacerlo dándoles una clase específica a cada checkbox (en el ejemplo es "impugnable") y añadiendo un nuevo elemento al formulario por cada checkbox no marcado en el momento del submit.

```js
window.onload = () => {
    const login = document.getElementById('login');
    login.onsubmit = (e) => {
        var checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName("impugnable");
        [].forEach.call(checkboxes, function (element) {
            if(!element.checked){
                var newField = document.createElement("input"); 
                newField.name = element.name;
                newField.value = "off"; //element.value;
                login.appendChild(newField);
            }
        });
    }
};
```

```html
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" id='login' method="post" action="#" onsubmit="onSubmit()">
<input type="checkbox" id="im1" name="impugnar[0]" class="impugnable" value="0"> Impugar pregunta...<br />
<input type="checkbox" id="im2" name="impugnar[1]" class="impugnable" value="1"> Impugar pregunta...<br />
<input type="checkbox" id="im3" name="impugnar[2]" class="impugnable" value="2"> Impugar pregunta...<br />
<input type="checkbox" id="im4" name="impugnar[3]" class="impugnable" value="3"> Impugar pregunta...<br />
<input type="checkbox" id="im5" name="impugnar[4]" class="impugnable" value="4"> Impugar pregunta...<br />
<input type="checkbox" id="im6" name="impugnar[5]" class="impugnable" value="5"> Impugar pregunta...<br />
<input type="submit" value="Enviar" />
</form>
```

Después, el PHP lo puedes recorer así:

```
<?php

    foreach($_POST['impugnar'] as $key => $value){
        echo "$key : $value <br />";
    }

?>
```

Lo que produciría una salida del tipo:

> 0 : 0
> 2 : 2
> 1 : off
> 3 : off
> 4 : off
> 5 : off

El orden de los elementos del array es debido a que, al insertarlos de esta forma, se cuelan antes que los demás. Pero si le añades el índice que les corresponde a cada uno en el name del input (name="impugnar[#]") después es sencillo identificar a cuál corresponde cada uno.

He puesto comentado junto a la asignación del valor del campo la entrada "element.value". Si usas eso, el nuevo campo llevará el valor que le hubieses asignado en el input, pero no podrías saber si se chequeó o no.